# Windows keyboard on mac - how to remap the newline key

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard

I have a MacBook Pro (OS X El Capitan)

I've plugged a Windows keyboard into the USB port; but the newline (?) button isn't correctly mapped. When clicked, it gives a new page, and not a new line.

Is there a solution for that?

Comment: I've translated your question into English (SO est un site anglophone.) You might get a better response on ServerFault, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the app Karabiner https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/, with this app you can remap any key on your keyboard to another key.

Bonne chance :)